# How to get Links field in http request GO

Tags: go

I found this code snippet

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse

def get_commits_count(self, owner_name: str, repo_name: str) -> int:
    """
    Returns the number of commits to a GitHub repository.
    """
    url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{owner_name}/{repo_name}/commits?per_page=1"
    r = requests.get(url)
    links = r.links
    rel_last_link_url = urlparse(links["last"]["url"])
    rel_last_link_url_args = parse_qs(rel_last_link_url.query)
    rel_last_link_url_page_arg = rel_last_link_url_args["page"][0]
    commits_count = int(rel_last_link_url_page_arg)
    return commits_count
```

And I need to do the same in Go. As it seems to me that I need to use something like "links" field (or whatever it is) in Go, but I can't find anything like this.

I'm stuck because I don't know what represents "links" in HTTP requests in Go.

Comment: Get the [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link) [response header](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Response.Header) like this: `links := resp.Header["Link"]`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it now and let you know if it works!

Comment: Well, it worked, thanks, but all the rest is not as great, though I can implement parsing myself. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically we need to take Link response header by doing response.Header["links"]

```
links := resp.Header["Link"]
if len(links) == 0 {
    return 0
}
var badlyParsedPageNumber = strings.Split(strings.Split(strings.Split(links[0], ", ")[1], "; ")[0],
    "&page=")[1]
lastPage := badlyParsedPageNumber[0 : len(badlyParsedPageNumber)-1]
```